# javascript: document.dispatchEvent(CustomEvent) does nothing

Tags: javascript, jquery, document, custom-events

I have the following chunk of code

```
$(function(){

    var TaskEvent = new CustomEvent('TaskAdded',{
        detail: {
            message:'A task fue ponida, champion'
        },
        bubbles:true,
        cancelable:true
    });

    var btn = $("#boton");

    function HandleSugar(e){
        console.log(e.detail.message);
    }

    btn.click(function(e){

        document.dispatchEvent(TaskEvent);
    });

    $(document).on('TaskEvent',HandleSugar);

})
```

When clicking in the button (#boton) nothing happens. Any idea?

Some clarifications:

- The button is created, that is not the problem
- The console shows no error at all, that's why I'm lost
- The expected behavior is for the custom event 'TaskEvent' to be triggered, so when pressing the button the message will appear in console log.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are listening for `TaskEvent` but the event is actually `TaskAdded`.

```
$(document).on('TaskEvent',HandleSugar);
```

should be

```
$(document).on('TaskAdded', HandleSugar);
```